# Java Application Error Jung Library

Tags: java, eclipse, jung

I am trying to run a Project in Eclipse as a Java application. The error is in one of its class.

```
public static List<Graph<Integer, String>> graphList = new ArrayList<>(); // Java 7 syntax
public static Graph<Integer, String>[] graph = new Graph[100];

    // populate 'graph'

public static Graph<Integer, String> g=new SparseMultigraph<Integer,String>();
```

and the error is this :
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type Graph is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

I tried everything from configuring path to updating JRE system library. I  am using java.util.List too. 
Can anyone please throw some light on how to solve this problem . Thanks

Comment: Want to clear up the formatting of that source a little? What are the asterisks for, for example?

Comment: Check that you are importing the correct Graph class.

Comment: I am importing these classes from jung library : import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
      import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;

Comment: can it be you're working with [JUNG 1.7.6](http://javadox.com/jung/jung/1.7.6/doc/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Graph.html)? The `Graph` class there does not seem very generic. You would need [JUNG 2.0](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunggraphimpl201sourcesjar.htm) to be able to use the generic `Graph<V,E>`.

Comment: @MrTsjolder is most likely correct, i.e., you're using a version of JUNG that is pre-2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph interface needs Vertex and Edge types specified < V,E >.

```
public static Graph g=new SparseMultigraph();
```

Change the above code to something like this:

```
Graph<Integer, String> g = new SparseMultigraph<Integer, String>();
```

Refer link below for an example:
http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/BasicGraphCreation.java

If you still experience a problem, refer thread below:
[The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends E>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804287/the-type-collection-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments)

Comment: I tried it but the error is in this line I guess :  public static List<Graph<Integer, String>> graphList = new ArrayList<>();