# The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Tags: java

Iv read that I should be able to create an ArrayList by using the following code:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

however; when I do i get the error: "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments  "

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Euler1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> nuList = new ArrayList<>();


    }

}
```

Comment: You have imported `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends E>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804287/the-type-collection-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You imported the wrong class.

```
import java.awt.List;
```

It should be:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've read is for `java.util.List` not the `awt`-list. You need to change your import.

Comment: Actually the `java.util.List` is more appropriate.