# The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <CustomTypeName>

Tags: java, eclipse

I've read many similiar topics - but they did not fix my issue cause i am having good import:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

The issue is following:

```
The type Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <CustomClassName>
```

I am using `JRE` `1.8`

[image: JRE version]

`JAVA_HOME` `Variable` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
```

Java compiler:
[image]

What's wrong??

`maven compiler plugin`

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: @Eran it's production code and i am not allowed to share it

Comment: Check Project settings -> Java compiler -> Compiler compliance level

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have any nested class, enum or interface called `Iterator` in your source.

Comment: @RealSkeptic added screen

Comment: Do you use some build tool (maven, gradle, etc.)?

Comment: @rebelizant yes - maven

Comment: @yaml, does it use maven-compiler-plugin in the build process?

Comment: @rebelizant yes -added to main post configuration of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answear from a similar question might help you

> It's late but still replying, might be helpful for others who are still facing the issue. I was getting exactly the same issue. The List was proper with util.List. The solution was to order the exports of the libraries. If you are using Maven or any other Libraries :
>
> In Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order & Exports
>
> Check 'JRE System Libraries' should be above 'Maven Dependencies'
>
> This worked for me.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804287/the-type-collection-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments)

Comment: the option of `JRE` was unchecked there. When i checked it and move it above `Maven dependencies` the errors did got away.
This option is automatically unchecked after `Maven update project` option in `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 2):

For me the import was wrong.  I was using an IBM class with the same name.

```
import com.ibm.ws.objectManager.Iterator;
```

Changed this to the proper import and the error went away:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```